# querying for SOA records, Ignore NoAnswer error in dnspython

Tags: python, dns

When I do `dig -t NS www.cloudflare.com`,

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.cloudflare.com.        IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
cloudflare.com.     275 IN  SOA ns3.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2029950661 10000 2400 604800 300
```

Although it has no answers but from the authority section I can still get the SOA record.

But with dnspython,

```
answers = dns.resolver.query('www.cloudflare.com', 'SOA')
```

It would just raise exception: "The DNS response does not contain an answer to the question: www.cloudflare.com. IN SOA"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the documentation:

> This (`dns.resolver.query`) is a convenience function that uses the default resolver object to make the query.

In cases like yours it raises exception "dns.resolver.NoAnswer" which is right and as defined, because indeed there is no answer for this specific name **and** type.
There may be answer for the same name and other types, but not for that specific type.

However if you look at the documentation, and the function signature you can see it has this: `raise_on_no_answer=True`.

So if you change your code to add `raise_on_no_answer=False` in the `query` call you do not get any exception and you can manipulate the answer. You will need to get into the `response` part. Of course you need to add a lot of checks in the below code to make it cope with various edge cases.

```
answer = dns.resolver.query('www.cloudflare.com', 'SOA', raise_on_no_answer=False)
if answer.rrset is None:
    print answer.response.authority[0].to_text()


cloudflare.com. 139 IN SOA ns3.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2029950661 10000 2400 604800 300
```